# MySQL: Pass single row ID in form with multiple IDs

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Form is made from a function that prints out all rows that are awaiting approval;

```
function all_reviews(){
$query1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE first != '' && disp_state= '0' && rejected != '1'");
if (!$query1) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($query1);

// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
//review action buttons
        echo "<div class=\"rev_action\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$row['id']."\">";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"accept\" value=\"Approve\" class=\"success rev_button\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('review_action').submit()\">";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"reject\" value=\"Reject\" class=\"error rev_button\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('review_action').submit()\">";
        echo "</div>";
}
```

I'm guessing that the proper way is by printing out the row id in a hidden input. Problem is, there could be more than 1 row that print out at a time.

**How do I select the exact row related to the approve or reject button?**

html:

```
<form name="form" action="include/review_submit.php" id="review_action" method="post">

    <?php all_reviews(); ?>

</form>
```

php (review_submit.php):

```
//database server connection 
mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbusername","$dbpassword") or die(mysql_error());
//database connection 
mysql_select_db("esd_db") or die(mysql_error()); 

//data feilds from review form
if($_POST['button'] == "Approve") {
   //code to update given row with an approval status
}

//data feilds from review form
if($_POST['button'] == "Reject") {
   //code to update given row with an rejection status
}
//insert values into table
 mysql_query("UPDATE `reviews` ") or die(mysql_error());

 Print "Success"; 

?>
```

Comment: Can I create a distinct id for the buttons? Then use a regex to pull out the id and pass it into the MySQL UPDATE? Seems dirty... what do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always make each row a different form, and pass it to a dynamic URL, where the GetDATA would tell of which one you selected.

Or alternately, you could NOT use a form, and have each one link to a page. (Assume that the action page is action.php, and you have 100 rows. You could have action.php?row=1&ac=y, action.php?row=1&ac=n, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a checkbox for each row and move buttons from each row to bottom of the form if you want to use basic non-AJAX form:

```
<div class="rev_action">
  <input type="checkbox" name="select_row[]" value="1">
</div>
<div class="rev_action">
  <input type="checkbox" name="select_row[]" value="2">
</div>
<!-- ... -->
<input type="submit" name="accept" value="Approve" class="success rev_button">
<input type="submit" name="reject" value="Reject" class="error rev_button">
```

If you want using ajax you don't need do any changes above and need to add a click event for each button:

```
echo "<div class=\"rev_action\">";
echo "<input class="id_input" type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$row['id']."\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"accept\" value=\"Approve\" class=\"success rev_button\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('review_action').submit()\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"reject\" value=\"Reject\" class=\"error rev_button\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('review_action').submit()\">";
echo "</div>";
...

</form>
<script>
$('input.success.rev_button').click(function(){
  var review_id = $(this).siblings('input.id_input').attr('name')
  $.ajax({
    url: '/reviews/success',
    type:'POST',
    data: {id: review_id}
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob and therefore I'm a little intimidated by AJAX.

Comment: Then use the first way and on the server side the $_POST['select_row'] will be an array with selected review ids

Comment: With this specific design, each printed row has to have it's own approve/reject buttons.